# Touch event on ipad

Tags: jquery, ipad, events, touch

Do you know how I can run the touch event on ipad? I have a small problem on closing a submenu.

For example, if my sub-menu is unfolded and I aillor click, it automatically closes. My code below works fine, but not on the ipad.

Would you have an idea for it to work on ipad?

```
var navigation = $('.l-navigation');

$(document.body).click(function(e) {

    // Si le clic n'est pas sur la navigation

    if( !$(e.target).is(navigation) && !$.contains(navigation[0],e.target) ) {

            navigation.find('.submenu').slideUp(); // Alors on cache le sous-menu

    }

});
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery UI Touch Punch plugin](http://touchpunch.furf.com/) for touch events on touch devices. Give a try.